# Why is $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{2((-1)^{(n+2)}(n+1)^2)}2 =\frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+1)((-1)n+2(n+1))}{2}$?

Tags: factoring

Why is $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{2((-1)^{(n+2)}(n+1)^2)}2 =\frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+1)((-1)n+2(n+1))}{2}$?

My math book says it has to do with the fact that $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{n+3}=(-1)^{n+2}(-1)$

But it just doesn't click for me... Any help in understanding this is much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $(-1)^{n+k}=(-1)^n \cdot (-1)^{k}$. So $(-1)^{n+3}=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot(-1)^2=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be correct...  replace $(-1)^{n+1} $ by $(-1)^{n+3} $, since they differ by a factor  $(-1)^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

We can factor the term: $$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)}{2}$$ to give us: $$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)}{2} \left[n + (-2)(n+1) \right] $$ $$=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)}{2} [-n-2]$$ $$=\frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$ which is the same as the books answer.

Answer (score 1):

Factor out a common factor of, say, $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)}{2}$.

Now we have $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)}{2}(n + 2(-1)(n+1))$.

If we factor out *another* $(-1)$, we get $\frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+1)}{2}(-n + 2(n+1))$.

Answer (score 1):

write the left Hand side as
$$\frac{-(-1)^{n+2}n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{2(-1)^{n+2}(n+1)^2}{2}=\frac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+2}(n+1-n)}{2}$$